# Get navigation items in DevExpress eXpressApp Framework (XAF) application

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, xaf

I have a [eXpressApp Framework (XAF)](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Index/frameworks.xml) desktop application. The main window contains [Navigation pane](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument3198) with tree of items. Is there any way to obtain the list of navigation items in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a XAF application model can be extended using interfaces. It is really easy to extend it and intentify it. For example in your situation I would open the model using ModelEditor and navigate to the NavigationItems node. When there you can look at the yellow info panel at the bottom of your form it says **Member of interface:**DevExpress.ExpressApp.SystemModule.IModelApplicationNavigationItems

This means that that XAF extended the model using the IModelApplicationNavigationItems, so we all need to do is to cast it to that interface and use its properties.

`((IModelApplicationNavigationItems) Application.Model).NavigationItems.AllItems`

This approach has the same result as yours, however is strongly bound!

Answer (score 1):

It was not easy to find, but here is the solution:

```
var navigationItems = Application.Model.GetNode<IModelRootNavigationItems>("NavigationItems").AllItems;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is suitable to get the list of navigation elements from the application model (a meta data tier).
Alternatively, you can access the same information from the [ShowNavigationItemController.ShowNavigationItem.Items](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/clsDevExpressExpressAppSystemModuleShowNavigationItemControllertopic) property.

P.S.
In the future, I suggest you use [Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) to get official and guaranteed assistance on the use of DevExpress products. Note that FULL SUPPORT IS FREE during the evaluation period (30 days).